# Rally SDK 2 customapp.js error with timebox filtering

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm looking at setting up a timebox filtered app using the example in https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/timebox_filtering

when I try and run this in a custom HTML page I am getting the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) on the file https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/panel/CustomApp.js?_dc=1389131267320

How do I work around or resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Rally App Builder?  More than likely your actual app class name is different from what is specified in your config.json file.  They need to be the same.

```
//In your app.js...
Ext.define('My.Custom.App', {
    //app definition here
});

//config.json
{
    "className": "My.Custom.App"
}
```

Then just re-build it and you should be good to go.

Or otherwise if you are manually launching your app in your html file you just need to make sure the class name is correct in the Rally.launchApp call:

```
 Rally.launchApp('My.Custom.App');
```